# Streaming an in-memory generated file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, csvhelper

After trawling the internet for hours, I'm lost on how to solve my problem for ASP.NET Core 2.x.

I am generating a CSV on the fly (which can take several minutes) and then trying to send that back to the client. Lots of clients are timing out before I start sending a response, so I am trying to stream the file back to them (with an immediate 200 response) and write to the stream asynchronously. It seemed like this was possible with `PushStreamContent` previously in ASP, but I'm unsure how to structure my code so the CSV generation is done asynchronously and returning an HTTP response immediately.

```
[HttpGet("csv")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetCSV(long id)
{
    // this stage can take 2+ mins, which obviously blocks the response
    var data = await GetData(id);
    var records = _csvGenerator.GenerateRecords(data); 

    // using the CsvHelper Nuget package
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);

    csv.WriteRecords(stream, records);
    await writer.FlushAsync();

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv))
    {
        FileDownloadName = "results.csv"
    };
 }
```

If you make a request to this controller method, you'll get nothing until the whole CSV has finished generating and then you finally get a response, by which point most client requests have timed out.

I've tried wrapping the CSV generation code in a `Task.Run()` but that has not helped my issue either.

Comment: You can use [Response.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.body?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to write directly to the output stream instead of a MemoryStream. That won't do anything about `await GetData();` though. This has nothing to do with streaming or CSV generation.

Comment: That's fair enough, but can you suggest a means to restructure the code to allow for this? The old `PushStreamContent` class used to let you register a callback that would execute after an initial 200 response.

Comment: to write to the stream, just use `Response.Body`, eg `new StreamWriter(Response.Body)`. That won't make the slow query run faster though, and you'll still get a timeout. What does `GetData` do and why does it take 2 minutes? Fixing a bad query is probably a lot more efficient (and quicker) than background generation of CSV files.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I was following this tutorial which shows how you can respond with a 200 immediately, and then subsequently write to the output stream: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html

Comment: `GetData(id)` is a call outside of my control that loads data from a database.

Comment: how much data does it load? If it takes 2 minutes to load 100 rows, whoever wrote it should fix it.

Comment: 100k+ rows across multiple tables with associated JSON documents and then sent over RabbitMQ. This count will and can grow over time too, so whilst it might be possible to shave some time off the request, I can't rely on it always being sub 2 minutes for example.

Comment: This guy is using SSE for the problem: https://techblog.dorogin.com/server-sent-event-aspnet-core-a42dc9b9ffa9

Comment: 100K rows means background execution, not streaming. That operation can be long enough that the *request* itself aborts. Trying to use streaming or SSEs for a llong-running job is like using a hammer to drive a Torx screw. It's possible, but a Torx screwdriver is better.

Comment: In any case, PushStreamContent doesn't perform anything complex. You can create your own FileResult-based class that performs the entire read-convert-stream operation in its `ExecuteResultAsync` call. If you check the implementation of [FileStreamResult[(https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/FileStreamResult.cs) you'll see that you can either do the job yourself in that method, or call a DI-registered handler for this.

Comment: The default [FileStreamResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs) writes the headers and then writes the contents to the output. Earlier versions did all the job in FileStreamResult but separating result from executor allows you to change the behavior for the entire application through dependency injection

Comment: Based on what you've said and the answer below, I'm thinking that it might make more sense to trigger a file generation and then notify the user (via WebSockets?) when it is ready to download. How does that sound? How would you architect it?

Comment: Report engines work that way - rendering jobs run in the background. In ASP.NET Core you can do that using a hosted service, eg based on [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The browser should request a report and *somehow* get notified that the report is done. This can be done by polling the server, with push notifications through web sockets or using SignalR to abstract this.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. Yep, I've used SignalR before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a `PushStreamContext` kind of type built-in to ASP.NET Core. You can, however, [build your own `FileCallbackResult`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html) which does the same thing. This [example code](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/blob/cc09ad98f892f41b7eedf5e7adc1cf08b54a2492/Example/src/WebApplication/FileCallbackResult.cs) should do it:

```
public class FileCallbackResult : FileResult
{
    private Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> _callback;

    public FileCallbackResult(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> callback)
        : base(contentType?.ToString())
    {
        if (callback == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        var executor = new FileCallbackResultExecutor(context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this);
    }

    private sealed class FileCallbackResultExecutor : FileResultExecutorBase
    {
        public FileCallbackResultExecutor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(CreateLogger<FileCallbackResultExecutor>(loggerFactory))
        {
        }

        public Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileCallbackResult result)
        {
            SetHeadersAndLog(context, result, null);
            return result._callback(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, context);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet("csv")]
public IActionResult GetCSV(long id)
{
  return new FileCallbackResult(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"), async (outputStream, _) =>
  {
    var data = await GetData(id);
    var records = _csvGenerator.GenerateRecords(data); 
    var writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(stream, records);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
  })
  {
    FileDownloadName = "results.csv"
  };
}
```

Bear in mind that `FileCallbackResult` has the same limitations as `PushStreamContext`: that if an error occurs *in the callback*, the web server has no good way of notifying the client of that error. All you can do is propagate the exception, which will cause ASP.NET to clamp the connection shut early, so clients get a "connection unexpectedly closed" or "download aborted" error. This is because HTTP sends the error code *first*, in the header, before the body starts streaming.

Comment: Thanks so much Stephen. It was your original tutorial on `PushStreamContent` that I was basing my solution on!

Comment: Thanks for sample, but it appears that at least one byte should be sent to browser to show SaveFile dialog.

Answer (score 3):

If document generation takes `2+` minutes it should be `asynchronous`. It could be like this:

1. client sends request to generate document
2. you accept request, start generation in background and reply with message like `generation has been started, we will notify you`
3. on client you periodically check whether document is ready and get the link finally

You also can do it with [signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Steps are the same but it's not needed for client to check the status of document. You can push the link when document is completed.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're probably right, the generation should be made async. Just going to leave the question open a little longer before marking your answer as correct.